# Im not sure why i am getting a exception when trying to pass data on segue

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CatagoryToSets"]){
    BYFSetsViewController *controller = (BYFSetsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

   //throw exception when i try to set them
    controller.workOut.catagory = catagory.text;//<<UITextfield
    controller.workOut.excercise = excercize.text;

    NSLog(@"passing the values %@ \n and %@ ",catagory.text,excercize.text);
}
```

Im trying to pass data to the next view BYFSetsViewController WorkOut is a object that i created and has two NSStrings that i want the user to enter then pass to the next view
But i keep getting the error that it cannot write to that adress

the error message i get is

2014-03-20 19:31:11.423 Gym_Log_Book[25611:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController workOut]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d698c0'

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Would you care to actually include the error message in your question??

Comment: how are you declaring "`workOut`" in your BYFSetsViewController .h file?  are you *sure* the segue is to the BYFSetsViewController?

Comment: It's quite clear -- `controller` (regardless of how it's declared) is addressing a vanilla UIViewController, not some subclass.

Comment: I put a property in the BYFSetsViewCotroller.h like so @property(nonatomic,strong) BYFWorkOut *workOut; and i am 100% sure its the right segue

Comment: How would i change it to address my subclass? @Hot Licks

Comment: I have no idea what you need to change.  All I'm saying is that `controller` is not what you think it is.

Comment: Did you change the class of the view controller in the storyboard to  BYFSetsViewController?

Comment: I feel so dumb now thank you for the help I did not change the view controller to be my custom class